# First EXPERIMENTAL proof of indistinguishability of electrons

Tags: electrons, scattering, history, identical-particles

Fairly early on in Thermodynamics there was a suggestion that particles are generally indistinguishable because of entropy paradoxes.  Later on, my recollection is that somebody in the 1920's shot electrons at thin metal foils, observed the scattering, and concluded unambiguously that the electrons had to be indistinguishable because of the statistics of the scattering pattern.  Now Davisson and Germer shot electrons at nickel surfaces, not foils, and Rutherford was all about alpha particles.  In any event, I can't find any discussion of how their experiments commented on indistinguishability.  Discussions about their experiments seem entirely focused on their role in confirming De Broglie and atomic structure, respectively.  Who was it that did the first EXPERIMENTAL proof of electron indistinguishability based on scattering (or anything else)?  This amazing amazing experimental result seems to have kind of disappeared into the fog of history.

Comment: I think the electron diffraction experiments of Davisson&Germer and  Thomson&Reid confirming the *wave nature of electrons* is the experimental proof of indistinguishability.

Comment: @hyportnex Why would you not get the same result with distinguishable electrons? Indeed, since the experiment doesn't normally use polarized electrons, there are two distinguishable spin states involved, but you don't notice because they have identical diffraction patterns.

Comment: @JohnDoty Interesting comment but if the beam is unpolarized and you are not testing for the polarization of any of the electrons while in flight, then in what sense could you say that any two are distinguishable?

Comment: @hyportnex Because you could do the test, but you're simply not doing it.

Comment: @hyportnex But we see that the exclusion principle doesn't apply when the electrons are in different spin states, so nature treats them as distinguishable.

Comment: @JohnDoty I am not sure. The question is then whether the state is for an individual electron or for a collection of electrons? If I place a "V" polarizer (a magnet) after one of the holes to reject all "H" polarized dipoles will I still get an interference pattern? Surely, we will for the "V electrons" unaffected by the polarizer but what about the "H electrons" whose half will not pass the filter? For the record, I have no real experimental knowledge of any of this, and neither pretend to have one...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147049/discussion-between-john-doty-and-hyportnex).

Answer (score 1):

The first experimental evidence for indistinguishability of electrons was the observation that matter doesn't collapse. Of course, in the paleolithic this fact wasn't remarkable. The discovery of the electron and the results of the Rutherford experiment made it profoundly mysterious. The success of modeling this (and many other observations) as a consequence of indistinguishability via the Pauli exclusion principle is what causes us to use it as a central feature of quantum models.

Comment: Re:"The first experimental evidence for indistinguishability of electrons was the observation that matter doesn't collapse." Are you sure? Bosons are indistinguishable too. Yet they can be collapsed into each other but not exactly.

Comment: @DukeWilliam Indistinguishability has different theoretical consequences for the behavior of fermions and bosons.

Comment: Is that a consequence of spin difference?

Comment: @DukeWilliam We call particles with integer spin quantum numbers bosons. If they have half integer spins, we call them fermions. And yes, the difference has consequences, as suggested by theory and verified by experiment.

Comment: ...mm. I mean what does matter doesn't collapse has to do with indistinguishability? Indistinguishability is not a very clear term. For example, a particle can be distinguishable in other aspects like spin direction and energy or momentum while being indistinguishable in charge at the same time. What does it have to do with whether matter collapse or not? For example, if you have different electrons with different charges will it cause matter to overlap the same spacetime coordinates?

Comment: @DukeWilliam Because the theory behind the Pauli exclusion principle depends on indistinguishability, and the exclusion principle is how our models capture the fact that matter doesn't collapse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147083/discussion-between-duke-william-and-john-doty).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems like what I was looking for was the experimental results of Chadwick on alpha particle scattering off helium.  [Chadwick J. 1930. The scattering of α-particles in helium. Proc R Soc Lond A. 128(807):114–122. Chadwick J, Bieler ES. 1921. C. The collisions of α particles with hydrogen nuclei. Phil Mag. 42 (252):923–940.]

As discussed on page 492 of [Niels Kjærgaard (2021) Effects of quantum mechanical identity in particle scattering: experimental observations (and lack thereof), Journal of the Royal Society of New Zealand, 51:3-4, 489-512, DOI: 10.1080/03036758.2021.1969957], the scattering pattern was shown experimentally and unambiguously to require indistinguishable alpha particles/helium nuclei.

I don't think this result is appreciated enough.  Proving the wave nature of electrons by scattering, as well as the nature of atomic structure is  all good and grand, but absolute experimental proof of indistinguishability is mind blowing!  Who would have thought such a thing was possible?  There will never be an alpha particle with a nick or a smudge or a manufacturing defect.  What a beautiful experiment! (Sure, it's really just a consequence of the wave nature of particles, but still, how remarkable!)

Comment: They are not necessarily indistinguishable in the sense they can have different energies, spin directions and polarization (for photons).

Comment: Yes.  Indistinguishability is not the same thing as being identical.  Particles that are identical and separated at a classical distance are not indistinguishable, even if identical.  But when their waveforms start overlapping, we lose track of which is which and they become indistinguishable.  The term "indistinguishable" is thus kind of sloppy terminology.